# Still failing a function, not sure why...ideas on test cases to run?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to get this Sudoku game working, and I am still failing some of the individual functions. All together the game works, but when I run it through an "autograder", some test cases fail..
Currently I am stuck on the following function, placeValue, failing. I do have the output that I get vs. what the correct one should be, but am confused..what is something going on?

EDIT: I do not know what input/calls they make to the function.

What happens is that "invalid row" is outputted after every placeValue call, and I can't trace why..

Here is the output (mine + correct one) if it's at all helpful: http://pastebin.com/Wd3P3nDA

Here is placeValue, and following is getCoords that placeValue calls..

```
void placeValue(Square board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE])
{   
    int x,y,value;  

    if(getCoords(x,y))
    { 

        cin>>value;

        if(board[x][y].permanent)
        {
            cout<< endl << "That location cannot be changed";   

        }
        else if(!(value>=1 && value<=9))
        {
            cout << "Invalid number"<< endl;
            clearInput();
        }
        else if(validMove(board, x, y, value))  
        {
            board[x][y].number=value;
        }
    }
}


bool getCoords(int & x, int & y)
{
    char row;
    y=0;

    cin>>row>>y;
    x = static_cast<int>(toupper(row));
   if (isalpha(row) && (x >= 'A' && x <= 'I') && y >= 1 && y <= 9)
   {
      x = x - 'A'; // converts x from a letter to corresponding index in matrix
      y = y - 1;   // converts y to corresponding index in matrix
      return (true);
   }
   else if (!(x >= 'A' && x <= 'I'))
   {
    cout<<"Invalid row"<<endl;  

    clearInput();
    return false;
   }
   else 
   {
    cout<<"Invalid column"<<endl;
    clearInput();
    return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: Which is the autograder? Is it an online judge like SPOJ or what? Maybe you print more whitespace or empty lines than needed. Or your output doesn't end with a newline in every place.

Comment: its whatever the department uses to check program output. if their program's output doesn't match mine, it says the function fails

Comment: What is the clearInput() method doing? You can paste it.

Comment: void clearInput()
{ 
 cin.clear();
 cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
}

Comment: Why are you doing cout<< endl << "That location cannot be changed"; instead of cout<< "That location cannot be changed" << endl; ?

Comment: That grader seems strange to me. Is it a requirement to use this clearInput() method to run through the grader?

Comment: @your first comment: I wasn't sure if the cout formatting was throwing off the function. There a function following (deleteValue) that has the same output, but I pass that one..

@your second comment: clearInput is supposed to be used to clear user input when there is an error..

Comment: Erm, difficult to say without knowing the input from `cin>>row>>y;`

Comment: Yeah no kidding, right? We're supposed to anticipate the input.
I am not understanding why it's calling 'Invalid row' and prior printing "that location cannot be changed"

I cannot reproduce this. If cin>>row>>y, row=out of range, it just prints invalid row, does not print anything else.

Comment: Well sorry for not realising you didn't know what the input was. That wasn't obvious.

Comment: Edited now.

is it possible that i should call clearInput after something like "That location cannot be changed"..if i don't, then that input gets read in and checked for valid row..?

Comment: Do they give you rules for input? For example, do they explicitly say that if the row/column is invalid there will be no value? What does clearInput do?

Comment: Working blind like this is pointless. The grader shows you your program's output, right? So just echo stdin to stdout, and then paste it here so we can see what you're *supposed* to be processing. `string s; while (getline(cin, s)) cout<<s<<endl;`

Comment: @tzaman: can't afford to do this w only 2 submissions to the autograder per day, with the project due tomorrow night.

Comment: @igor: I'd gladly blow one submission if it guaranteed the next one would be perfect, over continuing to take shots in the dark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's printing invalid row after *every* input, we have to conclude that your code is doing what it says: It thinks that every row is outside the range A-I. Most likely some input got your cin into a frozen state and the cin >> row is actually either sticking a 0 or nothing at all into row, and thus it's constantly failing the check and printing the message.

Answer (score 2):

(Replicating my comment on the original post) Working blind like this is pointless. The grader shows you your program's output, right? So just echo stdin to stdout, and then paste it here so we can see what you're supposed to be processing: `string s; while (getline(cin, s)) cout<<s<<endl;`

Meanwhile:

Your `clearInput()` function is simply reading and ignoring till the end of the line if there's a parse error; if that's how they're doing it, it'd be far easier to just use `getline()` to read a line and then parse it.

Just for kicks, here's a much more robust version of your `getCoords` function:

```
bool getCoords(int& x, int& y, int& value)
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    istringstream ss(s);
    char a, b, c;
    ss >> a >> b >> c >> ws;
    if (ss.fail() || !ss.eof()) return false;
    a = toupper(a);
    if (a < 'A' || a > 'I') return false;
    x = a - 'A';
    if (b < '1' || b > '9') return false;
    y = b - '1';
    if (c < '1' || c > '9') return false;
    value = c - '1';
    return true;
}
```

1. It reads in the input a line at a time, so you don't need to use a silly `clearInput()` anymore.
2. It reads in three characters, and three only; any more or any less and it'll skip the line and return false; any problems trying to read and it'll return false. (Not sure if that's how you're *supposed* to do it, but if you only want perfectly well formed lines, it's the way to go).
3. It performs all your range validation before returning true, so your outer function doesn't need to worry about it.

Just replace your `getCoords(x,y)` call with a `getCoords(x, y, value)`, and take out the `cin>>value;` line.

Comment: you don't want the ss >> ws. ws wasn't decalred.

Comment: thanks for the work, but i am limited as to what my calls have to be.
getCoords HAS to be getCoords(x,y)

honestly, this is the worst project ever.

the professor/GSIs have also stopped answering my emails, but many others have the same issues as per the posts on the classes forum.

ugh.

Comment: @igor: that sounds like a godawful course. Nothing I hate more than being *forced* to do things in a brain-dead way by a course / instructor.

Comment: exactly the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably also fix this line:

```
cout << endl << "That location cannot be changed";
```

to

```
cout << "That location cannot be changed" << endl;
```

---

A *possible* fix might be that if the row is invalid, you should NOT read the column. This is a very vague guess though.

This would assume that the input looks something like

```
A1 9
C3 3
d 9 8
q
A3 9
```

Your parser would fail at that input... I'm not sure how mean they are being with the input though.

I'm also not sure how much freedom you're being given to implement this, but if you're parsing line by line, it's often better to use getline(), and then parse each string. That would require some refactoring though.

---

Again, with the really mean input. Does anyone here think that they would give the following input?

```
A 1 3
A 
A 2 4
```

In that case, (s)he would really have to use getline() or noskipws and some additional parsing logic that would be fairly mean in a homework setting.

---

To give some explination on why I'm guessing this, it seems that you are missing lines of output. This would seem to me that in each input reading stage, you might be reading two lines of input, instead of just one.

Comment: i asked in regards to the input, and was told that "all input needed will be on the same line"

Comment: The question to ask is more if they will feed you not well-formed input. For example, the second to last line of either example I gave.

Comment: I had asked that exactly, and what i was told I already mentioned.

my partner had a cin.fail() element involved in checking input, we haven't ran that through the autograder yet, though.

Comment: Well, that doesn't really answer my question. If they will give you input such as "A\n", then your parser will fail that.

Answer (score 0):

Got further clarification from the Prof:

If the user types in 'P' and then presses enter, the program is to wait for further input (meaning it is waiting for the row, then the y then the value)

So, I do not need to account for input like

```
A
```